# Rewrite rule to add .html suffix

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using WordPress. I need to add a custom rewriterule. I want to have two URLs for a single page.

For example:

> **www.test.com/abc** <--- At present this is implemented & working fine.
>
> **www.test.com/abc.html** <--- Need to add .html at back side.

I want to allow access to the same page with `.html` extension.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I explain through comments.

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Make sure it's not an actual file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Make sure the hostname is www.test.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com

# If the request matches "abc.html", rewrite to abc
RewriteRule ^abc\.html$ abc [L,QSA]

# If you need to make this a generic rule, try this instead:
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [L,QSA]
```

Feel free to drop the `L` flag, if it's not the last rewrite rule. See [RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html) for more information on this.

You can [test it online](http://htaccess.mwl.be/):

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :) It's working.. Now I would like to keep dynamic value instead of "abc".. So (\w+) should be work right?

Comment: That'd be `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1 [L,QSA]`